# magento 1.8 user Login not working and in Login page " /> code displayed

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, form-key

User login not working and it not displayed error message also.

And the following code will shows **" />** in `login page`, `chechout page`

```
 <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Already i faced this problem, but that automatically solved.

> Note : Am using coolbaby magento 1.8 theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this error using the following steps:

1. Go to `system->index Management` select all and click submit to re-index.
2. Go to `system->cache management` click **flush magento cache** button to flush the cache
3. Go to `var/cache` select all `delete` to clear all cache from your root directory.